# Using except to find certain rows in sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to find rows from one table where they don't have a corresponding record in another table.

```
 SELECT CUST_NUMBER,
             REFNUMBER,
             'Application No Longer Exists; ' as Exception
              from Data
              except 
              select CUST_NUMBER
              from applications
```

The problem is SQL doesn't like mismatched column counts. How can I get the missing rows and associated information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
* from data t1
where not exists(select 1 from applications a where a.cust_number=t1.cust_number)


;With cte
as
(
select cust_number from data
except 
select cust_number applications 
)
select * from data where cust_number in (select cust_number from cte)
```

Comment: It's not important because your solution works, but can this not be done using except?

Comment: if you meant to say ,using except,i have added one.But i dont prefer that,since you dont have same columns and you have to access table twice